# Process input data to a correct format for a custom NER BERT model

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

I want to train a custom NER BERT model. Therefore I need to process my input data in a certain way.

My `df_input` looks like this:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'DocumentText': ['This is a doc 12 ab', 'document 13 a xx'],
                         'KeyWord1' : ['doc', 'document'],
                         'KeyWord2' : ['12', '13'],
                         'KeyWord3' : ['ab', 'xx']
                        })
```

```
DocumentText                KeyWord1       KeyWord2      KeyWord3
This is a doc 12 ab         doc            12           ab
document 13 a xx            document       13            xx
....
```

All the text in the `DocumentText` column should be tokenized. Then all the tokens should receive the tag `O` and each token that matches with a `KeyWord` column should receive the tag corresponding to the column name.

What it should look like:

```
Word       DocNr      Tag
This       1          O
is         1          O
a          1          O
doc        1          KeyWord1
12         1          KeyWord2
ab         1          KeyWord3
document   2          KeyWord1
13         2          KeyWord2
a          2          O
xx         2          KeyWord3
```

**I have code working but it is very slow; it takes many hours.** So after using a `for`-loop I tried the `apply` method with a lambda function but I'm getting stuck on that one because it gives a `Series` object back with a `DataFrame` for each documemt on each row.

```
def preprocess(doctext, docnr, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Word'])
    df1['Word'] = nltk.word_tokenize(str(doctext))
    df1['DocNR'] = docnr
    df1['Tag'] = 'O'
    df1['Tag'][df1['Word'] == keyword1] = 'KeyWord1'
    df1['Tag'][df1['Word'] == keyword2] = 'KeyWord2'
    df1['Tag'][df1['Word'] == keyword3] = 'KeyWord3'
    return df1

for i in range(0, 50000):
    try:
        df = df.append(preprocess(df_input['DocumentText'][i], 
                                  i+1,
                                  df_input['KeyWord1'][i],
                                  df_input['KeyWord2'][i],
                                  df_input['KeyWord3'][i]),
                                  ignore_index=True)
```

```
pd.DataFrame(df_input.apply(lambda row: preprocess(row['DocumentText'], 
                                        row.name,
                                        row['KeyWord1'],
                                        row['KeyWord2'],
                                        row['KeyWord3']),
                                        axis=1))[0]
```

Are there any other ways to achieve this result quickly?

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: `apply` still loops under the hood, so I'm not sure why you're expecting a speedup

Comment: You need to use the same tokenizer as the model, in your case, since you are working with Bert models, a NLTK tokenizer would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.explode` with `Series.map` for better performance:

```
In [736]: df_input.DocumentText = df_input.DocumentText.str.split()

In [713]: x = df_input.explode('DocumentText')
In [715]: y = x.iloc[:, 1:].drop_duplicates()

In [716]: d = {i:y[i].values.tolist() for i in y.columns}

In [733]: d = {i:k for k,v in d.items() for i in v}

In [724]: x['tags'] = x.DocumentText.map(d).fillna(0)
In [726]: x['DocNr'] = x.index + 1
In [730]: res = x[['DocumentText', 'DocNr', 'tags']].reset_index(drop=True)

In [731]: res
Out[731]: 
  DocumentText  DocNr      tags
0         This      1         0
1           is      1         0
2            a      1         0
3          doc      1  KeyWord1
4           12      1  KeyWord2
5           ab      1  KeyWord3
6     document      2  KeyWord1
7           13      2  KeyWord2
8            a      2         0
9           xx      2  KeyWord3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty fast:

```
e = df.assign(DocumentText=df['DocumentText'].str.split('\s+')).explode('DocumentText')
keywords = e.filter(like='KeyWord')
col_idxes = np.sum((e['DocumentText'].to_numpy()[:, None] == keywords.to_numpy()) * np.arange(1,keywords.shape[1]+1), axis=1)
tags = np.array(['O', *keywords.columns])[col_idxes]
out = e[['DocumentText']].assign(DocNr=e.index+1, Tag=tags).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  DocumentText  DocNr       Tag
0         This      1         O
1           is      1         O
2            a      1         O
3          doc      1  KeyWord1
4           12      1  KeyWord2
5           ab      1  KeyWord3
6     document      2  KeyWord1
7           13      2  KeyWord2
8            a      2         O
9           xx      2  KeyWord3
```

Comment: Why was this answer was downvoted? It works well and is very fast. It also answers the OP's question _"Are there any other ways to achive this result quickly?"_

Comment: Lol, thank you! Hey...@AloneTogether...isn't that a familiar name? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try first tokenizing each entry with `df.apply` and then matching the words to keywords:

```py
import pandas as pd
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DocumentText': ['This is a doc 12 ab', 'document 13 a xx'],
                         'KeyWord1' : ['doc', 'document'],
                         'KeyWord2' : ['12', '13'],
                         'KeyWord3' : ['ab', 'xx']
                        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'word': df1.DocumentText.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)})
df.index += 1
df = df.explode('word')
df = df.rename_axis('DocNr')
df['Tag'] = 0
df.loc[df['word'].isin(df1['KeyWord1'].to_numpy()), 'Tag'] = 'KeyWord1'
df.loc[df['word'].isin(df1['KeyWord2'].to_numpy()), 'Tag'] = 'KeyWord2'
df.loc[df['word'].isin(df1['KeyWord3'].to_numpy()), 'Tag'] = 'KeyWord3'
```

```
           word       Tag
DocNr                    
1          This         0
1            is         0
1             a         0
1           doc  KeyWord1
1            12  KeyWord2
1            ab  KeyWord3
2      document  KeyWord1
2            13  KeyWord2
2             a         0
2            xx  KeyWord3
```